# Will declaring multiple string literals with the same content allocate additional memory?

Tags: c#, memory-management

I'm curious about string allocations. If I have a constant called `mystring = "test"`, can I use "test" anywhere in the application without allocating any new data?  See below, will this method allocate any new data?

```
const string mystring = "test"
void test()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 100000;i++)
    {
        allocationTest();
    }        
}

void allocationTest()
{
    Console.Write("test");
}
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern.aspx

Comment: Sweet , thanks Slaks it finally clicked after reading that :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the method will not allocate any data.

The compiler will consolidate any duplicate string literals, so the two tring literals `"test"` will actually be one string that is created when the application starts.

Also, even if the string wouldn't exist in two places, a string literal is never allocated when you use it, it's allocated when the application starts. Having the constant that references the string makes no difference for the string literal used in the method.

Comment: Thanks , I was always under the impression a new object was always made when using quotes. I read about it and still was skeptical , needed some reassurance :)

Answer (score 1):

If the compiler finds two constant string values in your code in one project, it will use one instance.

If the compiled finds two constant string values in your code in more than one project, every project (dll or exe) gets its own instance. This is because the dll's/exe's should be able to function seperately.

If, during runtime, strings are created (for example, by reading a file line by line, or reading data from a database) each string (even if it has the same value) will become a seperate instance. This could be prevented by using the function string.Intern (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern.aspx).